# tracking error state space, linear control example

Tags: control-system, non-linear, state-space, tracking

I am trying to understand a detail from an example, from the control textbook *Slotine and Li (1991) "Applied Nonlinear Control", Prentice-Hall*, Example 6.4, pag. 220. A linear system is given:

$$\eqalign{
   \left[ {\matrix{
   {{{\dot x}_1}}  \cr 
   {{{\dot x}_2}}  \cr 
 } } \right] =& \left[ {\matrix{
   {{x_2} + u}  \cr 
   u  \cr 
 } } \right]  \cr\\ 
   y =& {x_1} \cr} 
$$

where the output \$y\$ is desired to track \$y_d\$. Differentiating the output, an explicit relation between \$y\$ -output- and \$u\$ -control input- is obtained:

$$\dot y = {x_2} + u$$

Until here it is clear. Now, the authors choose a control law:

$$u =  - {x_2} + {{\dot y}_d} - (y - {y_d})$$

and say that this yield the tracking error equation:

$$\dot e - e = 0$$

with the \$e\$ being the tracking error, defined as \$e=y-y_d\$ and the internal dynamics:
$${{\dot x}_2} + x = {y_d} - e$$
... and the problem continues.

**My question is**: how does one define the control law \$u =  - {x_2} + {{\dot y}_d} - (y - {y_d})\$ ?? And how does this relate to the two following equations (\$\dot e - e = 0\$ and \${{\dot x}_2} + x = {y_d} - e\$)?

Any clarifying answer is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: question moved to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665740/tracking-error-state-space-linear-control-example